MIME Type Errors. JS files being rendered like html
I have a website that I created a while back. Recently, I built a languages switching feature locally, and pushed it up through GitHub and into Vercel, expecting it to work just fine.
The page should have looked like this:

Instead, I got this result:

Now, this result is telling, when you look at the code. Here, let me send you the code directly connected with this page:
<!-- index.html -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <title>Contact</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Do you want your child to grow up knowing what really matters? If so, we will gladly teach them!">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
        <script type="module" src="/languageSwitch.js"></script>
        <script src="/indexComponent.js"></script>
        <link rel="icon" href="/logo.svg">
    </head>
    <body class=" bg-slate-200">
        <index-content></index-content>
        <img id="close" src="/close.svg" class="h-5 fixed top-14 right-5 -mr-2 mt-1 border border-red border-solid bg-slate-300 rounded-xl z-10 hover:bg-slate-400">
        <div id="btnsDiv" class="fixed right-2 top-14 bg-slate-800 pt-7 pb-4 pl-3 pr-5 rounded-sm grid gap-2 sm:flex">
            <button id="Spanish" class="text-sm bg-slate-300 px-2 py-1 mx-1 rounded-xl hover:bg-slate-400 text-slate-950">Español</button>
            <button id="English" class="text-sm bg-slate-300 px-2 py-1 rounded-xl hover:bg-slate-400 text-slate-950">English</button>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>

//indexComponent.js
class IndexContent extends HTMLElement {
  connectedCallback() {
      this.updateContent();  // Initialize with default content
  }

  updateContent(content = {}) {
      const { header = {}, main = {} } = content;

      const htmlContent = `
      <header class="shadow-md shadow-slate-700 w-screen py-2 bg-slate-800 flex justify-center items-center content-center">
        <nav class="w-fit flex justify-around items-center content-center">
          <p class="hover:bg-slate-700 px-2 py-1 rounded-sm text-slate-400 border-r border-solid border-slate-300/50"><a href="/good-news/gospel.html${window.location.search}">${header.linkOne || 'Good News'}</a></p>
          <p class="hover:bg-slate-700 px-2 py-1 rounded-sm text-slate-400 border-l border-solid border-slate-300/50"><a href="/index.html${window.location.search}">${header.linkTwo || 'Sign Up'}</a></p>
        </nav>
      </header>
      <main class="w-screen m-0 py-6 flex items-center justify-center">
        <div class="w-9/12">
          <h1 class="text-center font-bold h-5 text-2xl text-slate-900 py-2">${main.title || 'Contact Us'}</h1>
          <form action="https://getform.io/f/bejyndga" method="POST" class="grid justify-center p-8 gap-4">
            <div class="grid justify-center items-center content-center">
              <input class="mb-4 px-2 rounded-sm bg-slate-100 sm:w-60 md:w-80 w-52 text-sm py-1" type="text" name="Parent_Name" placeholder="${main.fields?.parentName || 'Parent Name'}">
              <input class="mb-4 px-2 rounded-sm bg-slate-100 w-52 sm:w-60 md:w-80  text-sm py-1" type="text" name="Child's Name'" placeholder="${main.fields?.childName || 'Child/Children\'s First Name(s)'}">
              <p class="text-xs pb-4 -mt-3 text-slate-900 w-52 sm:w-60 md:w-80">${main.fields?.fieldComment?.comment || '(if you have more than one child, separate their names with commas.)'}</p>
              <input class="mb-4 px-2 rounded-sm bg-slate-100  text-sm py-1" type="number" name="Phone_Number" placeholder="${main.fields?.phoneNumber || 'Phone Number'}">
              <input class="px-2 rounded-sm bg-slate-100  text-sm py-1" type="text" name="Address" placeholder="${main.fields?.address || 'Address'}">
            </div>
            <textarea class="px-2 rounded-sm bg-slate-100  text-sm py-1" name="Additional_Info" placeholder="${main.fields?.additInfo || 'If you need to give us additional information, feel free!'}" rows="6" cols="20"></textarea>
            <button type="submit" class="bg-slate-900 py-2 text-slate-50 rounded-3xl hover:bg-slate-800 active:bg-slate-950">${main.button || 'Send'}</button>
          </form>
          <p class="text-center py-4 -mt-8 italic text-sm">${main.alt || '(Or text us at (210) 549-6522)'}</p>
        </div>
      </main>
      `;
      this.innerHTML = htmlContent;
  }
}

customElements.define("index-content", IndexContent);

If you examine the code, you will see that only the html that is directly inside the index.html file is rendering. While the Web Component, along with the interpolated data is not displaying.
I’m getting three errors:

Details:
You can view the code on GitHub: https://github.com/QualityWebDev/Sunday_School
Thank you in advance!

The error is about languageSwitch.js, not indexComponent.js.

The issue is with the server - nothing in the code you posted will cause the server to do that - the last two errors suggest that the server is sending a (probably HTML) error page - check the response in the developer tools to see what the server is telling you

I did look at the network tab in the dev tools. Maybe I'm missing something, but it didn't shed any light for me. Here's a screenshot @JaromandaX: https://drive.google.com/file/d/10OliFIK4PeJBqcSch_OVHEg5RLYwJh5V/view?usp=sharing

did you look at the actual response the server sent, i.e. click on the request, look at the response text - the fact they are only 53 bytes in length suggests there won't be very much the server is sending as a response though - but it may be actual information about why your request is failing to fetch the correct file

Yes, I did. But, again, I must reiterate, I am far from expert. I wrote my first html a year ago.

and what does the response look like? Is it a state secret?

No! Here you go:
<!-- index.html -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
         (head content)
    </head>
    <body class=" bg-slate-200">
        <index-content></index-content>
        <img id="close" src="/close.svg" class="h-5 fixed top-14 right-5 -mr-2 mt-1 border border-red border-solid bg-slate-300 rounded-xl z-10 hover:bg-slate-400">
        <div id="btnsDiv" class="(classes)">
            <button id="Spanish" class="(classes)">Español</button>
            <button id="English" class="(classes)">English</button>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>


@JaromandaX thank you for your help!

I did get an answer to my question that worked. I got it in the Vercel community. I will post it here so that it can be of benefit to other folks on SO.
Digging deep on your vercel.json file, it looks like this is where the issue is. While this configuration might work to some extent, there are a few issues and potential improvements we can make based on your project structure and Vercel’s best practices.
The builds section is overly specific. You don’t need to list every single file. Vercel can handle static files automatically.
There is inconsistent file paths, some paths start with a slash, others don’t. This inconsistency could lead to unexpected behavior.
The routes section is more complex than necessary
It’s a good practice to specify the configuration version.
The last two route rules might conflict, potentially causing all requests to go to index.html.
We can simplify your configuration with:
{
  "version": 2,
  "builds": [
    { "src": "**", "use": "@vercel/static" }
  ],
  "routes": [
    { "src": "/good-news", "dest": "/good-news/gospel.html" },
    { "handle": "filesystem" }
  ]
}

This:
Specifies version 2 of the configuration schema.
Uses a single build step for all static files.
Routes /good-news to /good-news/gospel.html.
Uses the "handle": "filesystem" directive to serve all other requests from the filesystem as-is.
This configuration assumes:
Your main index.html is in the root directory.
You want /good-news to serve gospel.html from the good-news folder.
All other files (CSS, images, etc.) should be served from their actual locations.
If you need any specific routing beyond this, you can add more route rules before the "handle": "filesystem" line.
